# How to apply a soft shaped shadow to graphics which have transparent areas in them?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, image-manipulation, calayer

Normally I'm using CALayer shadowRadius, but now I also need to use UIImage and apply shaped shadows to it based on the content in the image.

For example when I have a layer with text in it and I set a shadow, it works automatically on the text and not just on the rectangle of the layer.

In Photoshop this is known as "layer style" and it automatically works based on the shape of the image content.

I am afraid that I need to implement some Harvard-Stanford-MIT-NASA kind of hardcore logic to apply a shadow on a "shaped image", i.e. an image of an round icon where the areas around the icon are fully transparent.

I'm able to manipulate images on a per-pixel level as I'm doing this already to draw charts, so if there was an open-sourced implementation of some fantastic algorithms this would be fantastic. And if not: How does this basically work? My guess is I would "just" try to blur a grayscaled version of my image somehow and then overlay it with the non-blurred version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My guess is I would "just" try to blur a grayscaled version of my image somehow and then overlay it with the non-blurred version.

That's pretty much it, actually. Except instead of blurring a greyscaled version of the image, blur a solid-colored version of the image (i.e. keep the alpha channel, but make all pixels black). Although CALayer's shadowing should do this already for you.

If your images are already composited onto a background (i.e. without real transparency), you have a harder problem as you first need to "remove" the background before you can have the shape of the object in order to generate the shadow.

Comment: Sounds good but what do you mean by "Although CALayer's shadowing should do this already for you." - did I miss something? Can CALayer render it for me if I have such a partially transparent image? Would rock solid.

Comment: @openrog: Yes, CALayer does the shadow by taking the layer's composited alpha channel and doing more or less just what we discussed (unless you override this by setting a value for `shadowPath`).

Comment: @openfrog: `imageView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor;
        imageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 4);
        imageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
        imageView.layer.shadowRadius = 6;` works